# AWS Lambda: Service error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What does this error mean?

I have 5 Lambda Functions deployed using Java that worked perfectly but since this afternoon all of them started displaying the same message when I execute each:

```
Service error.
```

No output, no logs, only that message in a red box.

In http://status.aws.amazon.com/ they say:

> 6:05 PM PDT We are investigating increased error rates and elevated
>   latencies for AWS Lambda requests in the US-EAST-1 Region. Newly
>   created functions and console editing are also affected.

Why does it happen and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for AWS support, not something the community can answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From time to time, parts of Amazon's AWS service fail. Sometimes the failure is very small and short-lived, and in other cases there are larger distributed failures.

Your system design needs to take into account the possibility that the piece of AWS that you are counting on will not work at the moment, and try to route around the damage. For instance, you can run Lambda in multiple regions. (It already runs in multiple availability zones inside a single region, so you don't have to worry about that). This gives you some isolation against failures in any one region.

Getting distributed systems to work at small scale can be hard because the failures that you need to protect against don't happen very often. At large scale, you get systematic efforts like Netflix's "Chaos Monkey", which deliberately introduces failures so that automated processes can detect and correct those issues.

"A distributed system is one in which the failure of a computer you didn't even know existed can render your own computer unusable." -- Leslie Lamport

"When a Fail-Safe system fails, it fails by failing to fail safe." -- John Gall